# Exclude local files from maven builds without editing the pom.xml

Tags: maven, configuration

The output (e.g., log files, xml, tmp files) from local tools which are not embedded in the maven life-cycle are still included in the jar.

Although there exist several answers on this topic by using excludes in the pom, I do not want to do this because those files are local. The pom shared among team members and on github would just fill up with dozens of excludes, being useless for anyone else.

Is there a way to have an additional *local* settings/pom file where to add such things?

Comment: If you have log files for examples they should be located in the `target` folder and will not being packaged etc. What kind of local tools are you talking about?

Comment: One automatic java code generation tool (the resulting files have to be in the src/java/ directory to be used with eclipse), JNI scripts for C files, analyzer tool, comment header update tool, etc. The problem is, some log and tmp files are always put in the current working directory (not configurable). There are some nasty workarounds: for now, I have a script which moves all unwanted files out of maven scope, and moves them back afterwards. But still, I think its not "maven-like". I also don't want to simply delete those files and recreate every time.

Comment: Generating code into `src/java` is in Maven wrong, cause the code belongs to `src/main/java` apart from that it is in general wrong, cause this folder is under version control which results in updates. Generated code always in `target/generated-sources` plus subfolder

Comment: My mistake, I forgot the `main` part. The version control is not a problem, as this is easy configurable. The actual question still remains. How to not pollute the pom with additions that are not relevant for others?

Comment: If you have such a project and it is build like that you don't polute the pom it's just the way you have to configure the project to get it smoothly building. You are trying to say i need to configure things but i don't wan't to put the configuration into the pom file? That's a contradiction itself.  Furthermore i don't believe that those tools creating log files / tmp files is not configurable (like javah or a c-compiler). Apart from that a real basic example of how it looks like could really help in any kind of discussion.

Comment: Some tools just don't care about maven, e..g, we have a WCET analyzer that we run. It will never care about any maven conventions. The project is not mine, I cannot just reconfigure it as I like. Part of that project already exist when maven was not even around. All in all, I think it's just another case where for a quite simple task maven does not provide a simple solution. Take git for example, it's a no-brainer to set up local ignores and still have a shared ignore.

Comment: Git is something different than maven. But you have to change the configuration for git (.gitignore) so the same you have to do in Maven. No way around without changing the pom.